# BigQuery Temporary function converts int to string

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using bigquery with standart SQL. When I pass to a function int field, the function converts it to string.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION test_function(int_field INT64) RETURNS INT64

LANGUAGE js AS """
throw typeof(int_field)
//return int_field
""";

WITH

test_table as (SELECT 1 as int_field)

SELECT test_function(int_field) from test_table
```

Here is Error: `string at test_function(INT64) line 2, column 1`

Here is Job ID: `fabrika-okon:bquijob_2cb8c50e_15d9db59b4f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As JavaScript does not support a 64-bit integer type, **INT64 is
>   unsupported in input or output types for JavaScript UDFs**. Instead, use
>   FLOAT64 to represent integer values as a number, or STRING to
>   represent integer values as a string.

See more at [`SQL type encodings in JavaScript`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#sql-type-encodings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION calculateGender(gender NUMERIC) RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js AS
  "switch(gender){ case 0: return 'Male'; case 1: return 'Female';}";

SELECT calculateGender(0) as Masculino, calculateGender(1) as Femenino;
```